# assign the whole object for smarty

Tags: php, smarty

i'm using smarty as a temeplete engine
and i have one very big class and other classes extended to it and in each sub class i using

```
function __construct(mainclass &$mainclass) {
$this->mainclass= & $mainclass;
}
```

to use the main class vars in the sub class

and in the end of my code is

```
$this->assign( 'mainclass' , $mainclass);
```

which assign my db connection and all other things

my question is "is that wrong or true?"

Answer (score 1):

Rather than doing this you can also extend that class.
and you can use all class variables and functions of that file using $this keyword.

```
main.php
class main_class{
    private $var = 'a';

}

sub.php
class sub_class extends main_class{
   echo $this->var;
}
```

I think it should work for you.

Comment: I dont get you .. what you want to say? can you elaborate it?